# php glob images from a root level folder

Tags: php, glob

```
root  
    images (folder)   
    lorem.php     
    subdomain.example.com    
        index.php
    public_html
```

`index.php` - inside `subdomain.example.com`

```
include('../lorem.php'); // this works
$array = glob("../images/*");  // doesn't work, array is empty
```

it is logical - if `include` works - `glob` should also work, isn't it?
so is there a way to `glob()` images in the above scenario

Comment: It seems more likely that a permissions problem is to blame than anything to do with `..` being special.

Comment: @miken32 - maybe, but the permission is probably the same for all php functions

Comment: Probably? If anyone has the ability to check that, it would be you.

Comment: @miken32 - no, I'm not in the situation to check this until tomorrow, hosting support is in a deep sleep. And I'm pretty sure that `include` and `glob` are the same from the permission view of point

Comment: That's not true. `On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.` Quoted from [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Try `glob("../images/.*")` or have look into [realpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath).

Comment: @MarkusZeller - tried, without succes. And `glob("../images/*")` works fine if `images` is inside the subdomain

Comment: Make sure `www-data:www-data` has at least read access to `/images`.

Comment: Try with a command like `passthru("ls -la ../images");` if there is any error.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function passthru()`

Comment: What? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru Where did you do that?

Comment: @MarkusZeller - normally - inside `index.php` - before `doctype html`. Now I'm really confused, I see that's a regular function. If matters - I'm using php 8.0

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. The PHP functions are irrelevant, I'm talking about filesystem permissions. Just because you have access to `lorem.php` doesn't mean you have access to `images/`.

Comment: @miken32 - hmm... I see now your point. Maybe yo're right. Have you pls any idea about `passthru` - why I'm getting - `undefined function` error

Comment: No idea. Maybe an invisible whitespace? Try `exec()` or `system()`.